# How to add custom headers in django test cases?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tests

I have implented a custom authentication class in django rest framework
which requires client id and client secret on user registration in headers.
I am writing test cases for user registration like this:-

```
User = get_user_model()
client = Client()


class TestUserRegister(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # pass
        self.test_users = {
            'test_user': {
                'email': 'testuser@gmail.com',
                'password': 'Test@1234',
                'username': 'test',
                'company': 'test',
                'provider': 'email'
            }
        }

        response = client.post(
            reverse('user_register'),
            headers={
                "CLIENTID": <client id>,
                "CLIENTSECRET": <client secret>
            },
            data={
                'email': self.test_users['test_user']['email'],
                'username': self.test_users['test_user']['username'],
                'password': self.test_users['test_user']['password'],
                'company': self.test_users['test_user']['company'],
                'provider': self.test_users['test_user']['provider'],
            },
            content_type='application/json',
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def test_register(self):
        response = client.post(
            reverse('user_register'),
            headers={
                "CLIENTID": <client id>,
                "CLIENTSECRET": <client secret>
            },
            data={
                "first_name": "john",
                "last_name": "williams",
                "email": "john@gmail.com",
                "password": "John@1234",
                "username": "john",
                "company": "john and co.",
                "provider": "email",
            },
            content_type="application/json"
        )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here is my custom authentication class:-

```
from oauth2_provider.models import Application
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException


class ClientAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    @staticmethod
    def get_client_credentials(request):
        try:
            client_id = request.headers.get('CLIENTID')
            client_secret = request.headers.get('CLIENTSECRET')
        except:
            raise APIException(detail="Missing Client Credentials", code=400)
        return {
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret
        }

    def authenticate(self, request):
        credentials = self.get_client_credentials(request)

        client_instance = Application.objects.filter(
            client_id=credentials['client_id'],
            client_secret=credentials['client_secret'],
        ).first()

        if not client_instance:
            raise APIException("Invalid client credentials", code=401)
        return client_instance, None
```

But it is still giving me 500 internal server error
everything is working fine if I dont add the custom authentication to my register view.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: django 2.2.9 version

Answer (score 5):

To add custom headers you need to prefix them with HTTP_:

```
client.post(url, ..., HTTP_CLIENTID=<client id>, HTTP_CLIENTSECRET=<client secret>)
```

or using a dict:

```
headers = {"HTTP_CLIENTID": "Some id", "HTTP_CLIENTSECRET": "some secret"}

client.post(url, **headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) the way to pass headers is as additional keyword arguments

```
client.post(url, ..., CLIENTID=<client id>, CLIENTSECRET=<client secret>)
```